# Can't convert a string to double vb2008?

Tags: vb.net, string, double

I'm a noob to programming and am having a bit of trouble with some code i am attempting to write...

This may seem very trivial to the more expert crowd however, here it goes...

```
Private Sub CK_btn_Total_Bill_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CK_btn_Total_Bill.Click

    Dim totalPrice_1 As Double
    totalPrice_1 = totalPrice_1 + _
    CDbl(CK_txt_Quantity.Text) * _
    CDbl(CK_txt_Price.Text) * _
    System.Convert.ToDouble((100 + CK_txt_Tax.Text) / 100)
    CK_txt_Total.Text = totalPrice_1
```

When i test to debug, the rest of my code runs fine but these 6 lines are never executable.
the `CK_btn_Total_Bill_click` does not function...

can anyone please help?

Comment: This is an event handler, did you click the button?

Comment: Also it might be easier if you just convert to double using `Double.Parse` or `Double.TryParse` and I would recommend changing `System.Convert.ToDouble((100 + CK_txt_Tax.Text) / 100)` to `(100+Double.Parse(Iff(String.IsNullOrEmpty(CK_txt_Tax.Text),"0",CK_txt_Tax.Text))/100`

Comment: If your problem is that your code never runs, conversion of string to double is irrelevant. Replace all your code in question with `Debug.WriteLine("Hello")`. Place a breakpoint on this statement. If it still never runs, problem is NOT with your 6 lines, it's **how you pass control** to those 6 lines. After the experiment, adjust your question accordingly and provide more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the handler isn't firing then the event isn't calling it.  Could you have changed the name of the button?  I'm not sure if VS2008 will automatically update every call to that button when you change the name.

One of your problems could be here:

```
System.Convert.ToDouble((100 + CK_txt_Tax.Text) / 100)
```

You're trying to do a math operation with a string value, instead of converting it to a number.  Something like this might work:

```
Dim CKTax,CKQuantity,CKPrice As Double
If Double.TryParse(CK_txt_Quantity.Text, CKQuantity) AndaAlso _
   Double.TryParse(CK_txt_Price.Text) AndAlso _
   Double.TryParse(CK_txt_Tax.Text, CKTax) Then

    totalPrice_1 = totalPrice_1 + CKQuantity * CKPrice * ((100 + CKTax) / 100)
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

If the event doesn't trigger, means that the problem is **NOT** with the codes but rather with the handler.

Please, verify that your button name is `CK_btn_Total_Bill`

however, you'll need to verify that your textboxes are not null also before trying to convert, which may lead to conversion exception. Or use the `Double.TryParse` to try conversion before doing any mathematical operation.